# MySQL regexp list

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a MySQL table with column `regexp` and column `value` like:

```
regexp    value
 ab+c      abc
 bc+d      bcd
```

Also I have a list of values like: (not in database, its in query)

```
abc
abbc
bcccccd
```

I need to match the values in the list to the regexps and get the values for each item - expected output:

```
match    value
 abc      abc
 abbc     abc
bcccccd   bcd
```

If this wasn't a regexp I could use

```
select `regexp`, `value`
from `mytable`
where `regexp` in ('abc', 'abbc', 'bcccccd')
```

But I can't use this to match regexp. Even if there is some sort of `regexp in` this will still be problematic because it will return the regexp and not the value that matched - unwanted output:

```
regexp    value
 ab+c      abc
 ab+c      abc
 bc+d      bcd
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do something like:

```
select rt.value from regextable as rt where 'bcccccd' rlike rt.regexp
```

And use one query per input value.

Comment: But that will be really slow, I need about 100k queries like that.